# Determining specific user action that triggers a "bounds_changed" event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to be able to keep my map centred and zoomed according to my `LatLngBounds` when the viewport size changes, but not when a user drags or zooms. I'm using the `"bounds_changed"` event along with `fitBounds()` to keep it centred and zoomed properly for viewport changes, but when the map is dragged or zoomed the bounds also change so `fitBounds()` is essentially preventing these actions too.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(49.8994, -97.1392),
    zoom:1,
        draggable: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.803060, -97.229094),
    new google.maps.LatLng(49.963223, -97.054686)
  );
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#EventArguments) I should be able to access event properties, so I thought I'd check for something that would indicate what specifically triggered the "bounds_changed" event, but the event is showing as undefined in the console.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
  console.log(event)
});
```

I can access properties for simple "click" event but not "bounds_changed", so I'm not sure if there is even supposed to be properties for "bounds_changed", or if there is a completely different approach to accomplishing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The `bounds_changed` event doesn't have properties (per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) ): `bounds_changed **None** This event is fired when the viewport bounds have changed.`

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks. I guess it's just about reading the docs, 101.

Answer (score 0):

```
var drag = false;
var zoom = false;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    if (!drag && !zoom) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    zoom = false;
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
    drag = true;
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    drag = false;
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoom = true;
});
```

Comment: This works but am wondering if there's any other way to do it.